# LINQ Select Distinct objects from a List(Of T) on multiple properties does not work

Tags: vb.net, linq

My goal is to select the objects based on three `properties`: `CreatedBy, GrantedTo, PatientID`.
The following is the data I'm having in my `List(Of Access)`

[image]

So from the above example I should be getting **two objects** only:

```
1) CreatedBy:1, GrantedTo: 65, PatientID: 48
2) CreatedBy:1, GrantedTo: 66, PatientID: 48
```

but I'm getting **eight**.

Here is my buggy code:

```
Dim distinctList As List(Of Access) = t.GroupBy(Function(p) New With {p.GrantedTo, p.PatientID, p.CreatedBy}).[Select](Function(g) g.First()).ToList()
```

I believe the code should select the first from each unique group of objects.

Any ideas?

Comment: What data you would like to get with?

Comment: @vipin The data is passed as a list(of access) as an input parameter from a function

Comment: What are the properties you wolds like to get by this code?

Comment: @vipin CreatedBy, GrantedTo, PatientID should be the filters. I'm trying to new unique objects with the above properties. i dont mind if the rest are null.

Comment: then, select those, you are selecting all fields now

Comment: [Select](Function(g) g.First()) this is not required. you remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a big flaw in your logic:

> So from the above example I should be getting two **objects** only:
>   1) CreatedBy:1, GrantedTo: 65, PatientID: 48
>   2) CreatedBy:1, GrantedTo: 66, PatientID: 48
>   [...]
>   I believe the code should select the first from each unique group of objects.

Yes, you can get your data grouped by CreatedBy, GrantedTo and PatientID.
**But** what you get back cannot be (reasonable) objects of type `Access` and it will not be the first from each group.

Why? Because when you want to select all data from your object - and thus `AccessID`, `PermissionID` etc. - what values should those attributes have?

In your example 1):
Should `AccesID` be 238 or 240?
Should `PermissionID` be 15 or 18?
...
I guess you got the point.

So what you actually should do is to select the grouped data only, not as `Access` objects but either as an anonymous type or an defined type.

Anonymous version:

```
Dim distinct = From acc In access
               Group By g = New With {Key .CreatedBy = acc.CreatedBy,
                                      Key .GrantedTo = acc.GrantedTo,
                                      Key .PatientID = acc.PatientID} Into Group
```

(The `Key` keyword is mandatory here!)

Now if you want to pass these distinct values to another object/function you can pass them as single paramaeters:

```
For Each value In distinct
     foo.bar(value.g.CreatedBy, value.g.GrantedTo, value.g.PatientID)
Next
```

Or you create an own small class which contains only the three properties.
(I leave this point out since I´m running out of time but it should be straight forward).

**EDIT**
Try the following (typed blindly and untested):

```
Dim distinct = (From acc In access
               Group By g = New With {Key .CreatedBy = acc.CreatedBy,
                                      Key .GrantedTo = acc.GrantedTo,
                                      Key .PatientID = acc.PatientID} Into Group
               Select New Access With {.CreatedBy = g.CreatedBy, 
                                      .GrantedTo = g.GrantedTo, 
                                      .PateintID = g.PatientID}).ToList()
```

This should give you a `List(Of Access)` with **new** Access objects with only the three properties set.

Comment: I don't mind which AccessID or PermissionID is selected. All I care is getting a unique object based on those three properties.  Your code seems to work. Can you modify the code so I get a List(Of Access) objects instead of creating a new class for the filtered objects?